# XML-Schema - new row in imported schema

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I create a xml-schema with the code from [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469857%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
Sub Create_XSD2()


Dim StrMyXml As String, MyMap As XmlMap
   Dim StrMySchema As String
   ' Book.xml is the file created in section one of this topic.
   StrMyXml = "C:\BookData.xml"

   ' Turn off async loading.
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ' Add the string to the XmlMaps collection.
   Set MyMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(StrMyXml)
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   ' Create an empty file and output the schema.
   StrMySchema = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).Schemas(1).XML
   Open "C:\BookData2.xsd" For Output As #1
   Print #1, StrMySchema
   Close #1
End Sub
```

After I import the data from the xml file everything is placed in one row. How can i change that?
Thanks,
Laurenz

Comment: are you sure you followed all the steps in the article? I have been just able to reproduce this just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the paths to the directory!